# how can we integrate help file in oracle forms 11g

Tags: oracleforms, helpfile

I need to show help contents in oracle forms 11g.

I can see "Help book title" property in form's property palette and "Help Book Topic" property in oracle forms items. But I am not able to get any information regarding how to use this.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those properties are no longer supported in Oracle Forms Services. They are relics from the client-server days (Oracle Forms 6i and earlier).

So, you're pretty much on your own for implementing help files. I suggest creating HTML files that are accessible from your Forms server and using the web.show_document() built-in to display them, perhaps from a menu item or button.